# Correct way to get aggregate value with group by

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables such as Customers and Purchases tables. And I try to get the customers who made more than 1 purchase in a certain year. So this is my current query

```
select c.name, c.email
from customers c inner join purchases p
    on c.customerid = p.customerid
where p.year = 2002
    group by c.name, c.email
```

The problem I am having right now is this query will result whoever make a purchase which is not exactly what I want. So I want to edit as:

```
select c.name, c.email
from customers c inner join purchases p
    on c.customerid = p.customerid
where p.year = 2002 and p in
    (select p.customerid, count(p.*) as total
    from purchases
    where total > 1
        group by p.customerid)
    group by c.name, c.email
```

And this query is full a syntax error. Some one help to give me an idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```
SELECT C.Name, C.Email
FROM Customers C INNER JOIN Purchases P ON C.CustomerID = P.CustomerID
WHERE P.Year = 2002
GROUP BY C.Name, C.Email
HAVING COUNT(P.CustomerID) > 1
```

Comment: + 1 Thank you, "having" solves the problem. Such a convenience statement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM Purchases
       WHERE Year = 2002
         AND CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID) > 1
```